# opencv cvLine method does not working

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to print a line on camera captured frame, but when I tried this snippet code it throws

```
cv::Mat cameraFrame
main method Mat
Error: no suitable conversion function for "cv::Mat" to "CvArr" exists
```

```
cvLine( cameraFrame, 
cvPoint(30, 30),
cvPoint(90, 90),
Scalar(255,255,255), 1, 8, CV_AA);
```

but at the same time I used `putText` method it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

`cvLine()` is a function from OpenCV's **C API** (now deprecated), but it's meant to work only with the `IplImage` data type.

`cv::Mat` on the other hand is from OpenCV's **C++ API**, as well as [`cv::line()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line), which is the appropriate C++ alternative to draw a line:

```
cv::line(cameraFrame,
         cv::Point2i(30, 30), 
         cv::Point2i(90, 90), 
         cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 1, 8, CV_AA);
```

Comment: I updated the answer, but the method signature in the docs is very clear about how to do this.